# Drupal 8 Twig : check if by general utility variables

Tags: drupal, twig

I want check something by general utility variables. I test something like this:

```
{% if logged_in %}
Hi dear
{% endif %}
```

that's work but when I use this type of if nothing happens:

```
{% if front_page %}
Hi dear
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if node_type == 'article' %}
Hi dear
{% endif %}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Try dump your vars with `{{ dump(VAR) }}` (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)

Comment: It's not 'front_page' but 'is_front' .... and 'node_type' should be 'node.type' ... no ?

Comment: @NuLLer - so you have an answer what's wrong in your code - those vars are null :)